# Anchor not working on Fixed position element in Mobile Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, fixed

When scrolling in Mobile Chrome anchors become unclickable when the address bars disappears, but you can actually activate the link clicking just above it. This happens on position fixed elements.

I have created a demo, you can check it in mobile

This is the fixed section CSS

```
footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background:#aaa;
  left:0;
  right:0; 
 }
 .content{
  padding:0;   
  }
```

And this is the main HTML

```
<div class="content">
  Content here
 <footer>
   <a href="#" class="link">My link here</a>
</footer>
</div>
```

And some JS to check the click/tap

```
  $('.link').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("clickd");
   });
```

https://codepen.io/markware/debug/jKRMxV

Can this be prevented via CSS?